# Exclude sub-directories from mod_rewrite rule

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, webserver

I'm using the code below to get all the parameters into a variable

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    Rewritebase /  
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

The problem I have now is; How to exclude a sub-directory from the rule, for example images, or assets?

I have tried a few things but I ended up with url like this **page.local/assets/?/assets**

Comment: I have tried the solution but when I have a directory witch exists on the server but is not in the rule. The URL becomes this http://page.local/test/?/test